# ggplot alpha = 0 not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate a trajectory plot of some longitudinal data with highlighting of random subject trajectories by adjusting the alpha value. I am 95% of the way there except I can't seem to get complete transparency of the line plots when alpha = 0 (it still appears grey). Any ideas? - the data is here:

https://d.pr/f/iIoE8q+

Thank you.

```
# Assign random alpha (0 [90%] or 1 [10%]) values
macs <-  ddply(macs, .(id), function(x){
  x$alpha = ifelse(runif(n = 1) > 0.9, 1, 0)
  x
})

# Loess fit
fit <- loess(CD4 ~ time, data=macs, span = 0.5)

# Plot
ggplot(data = macs, aes(x = fitted(fit), y = resid(fit))) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha=1), size = 0.5) +  
  geom_line(aes(alpha=alpha, group=id)) + 
  guides(alpha=FALSE)
```

[image: plot to replicate]

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has got to do with the `color` behavior in `ggplot`. A simple fix is to explicitly specify its color to be `NA` when the corresponding `alpha` is 0. Here's the code I would add before the `ggplot` call:

`color_rule <- ifelse(macs$alpha == 0, NA, "black")`

And slight modifications to `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(data = macs, aes(x = fitted(fit), y = resid(fit))) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha=1), size = 0.5) +  
  geom_line(aes(alpha=alpha, group=id), color=color_rule) + 
  guides(alpha=FALSE)
```

This would get you the following plot:
[image]

A clean, fully transparent `geom_line` by having `color=NA`. Just for comparison, ff you remove the `color=NA` argument from `geom_line`, even with `alpha=0` you'll get what is effectively the "default color" of the line:
[image]

Comment: Was just fighting with this in `ggplot 3.3.2` and even the solution above didn't make my lines completely disappear... there were still some phantom lines.  The thing I wasn't aware of is that there is a default alpha scale function that intentionally starts at 0.1 instead of zero.  The solution (which I may post later) is to use the `scale_alpha_*` family of functions (especially `scale_alpha_identity`).

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to reproduce the first chart, the x-axis should be time and the y-axis is the residuals of the fit. So you need to combine the original data `macs`, containing `time`, with the residuals in `fit`. I would use `broom::augment` for that.

For the alpha issue, you need to convert the values to factors then work with `scale_alpha_discrete`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

fit %>% 
  augment() %>% 
  bind_cols(macs) %>% 
  mutate(alpha = factor(alpha)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, .resid)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = id, alpha = alpha)) + 
    scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0, 1)) + 
    geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
    guides(alpha = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This works too.
I realised about my incorrect x-axis specification after I posted, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Following up on this, it seems like the default range for alpha is `c(0.1, 1)`.  This seems to work because it changes the bottom of the range from 0, not 0.1.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1))` will do it, because the default range of alpha is `c(0.1, 1)`.

```
iris$alpha = rep(c(0, 0.5, 1), length = 150)
ggplot(iris,
       aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, alpha = alpha, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you.